# How to find out in which nav menu is current page?

Tags: wordpress

A website I'm working on has a lot of menu items, so they were split into two menus. There's a more button which shows the second menu using JS (only one is shown at a time).

What I want to achieve is that when a user clicks on an item in the second menu, the second menu is displayed by default after reloading.

For this, I need to know if the current page is in the secondary menu, but I don't know how to access the menu items. More specifically, I can't find out what the ID of my menu is (I guess I should use the `wp_get_nav_menu_items` which needs a menu ID).

Comment: WordPress adds some classes to menu items, depending on how you've set up the menu (as submenu items for example). Do you have your website online, so we could have a look at the HTML, and see if there's any classes like `current-menu-item` applied?

Comment: The site is not online yet. But you gave me a good idea - I'm going to use the 'current-menu-item' class and somehow figure it out with pure JS. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress adds the **current_page_item** class on the li in the nav of the current page you are on. So you can use that class to style the current page item.

Comment: More exactly I needed to check this condition on document ready `if ( $( '#menu-wrapper-secondary' ).find( '.current-menu-item' ).length > 0 )` and then just show the secondary menu.